# TypeScript complains about non-existent properties in generic function

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript Generics to specify the parameter types a function accepts. As seeing below, `Foo` and `Bar`, both have a function called `isDirectory` but seems to be invalid in the generic function. Can anyone explain me what I am missing here?

```js
class Foo {

    isDirectory(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}

class Bar {

    isDirectory(): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}

type XYZ = Foo | Bar;

function bas<XYZ>(x: XYZ) {
    !!!!!!!! Property 'isDirectory' does not exist on type 'XYZ'.(2339)
    return x.isDirectory();
}
```

I know that I can extend the generic type with `extends`, but why would that be needed in this case? Is there a solution without manually typing an interface?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrqegSwgEWwCcBTYAF3kIE8AKASgC5oAjREYsAOxQyz5LIBXQtzKFBxANy9MAX1TzUoSDABCYQjxk58RUhWr0mreOy48+-YkJHQxE6X3mKyVAA7FoADQCaALWgAXjhEaAAfaHVCaVQAM0FOcmx4bmZIAB5fPwA+GgAPJiy6CywBYW48gDpcAhJySlo6aVkgA

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same name for multiple things. So while you think the `XYZ`'s are all related, they're not. Let me give them unique names so it's clear what is what:

```
type XYZ = Foo | Bar;

function bas<T>(x: T) {
  return x.isDirectory();
}
```

The function `bas` is a generic which accepts any type `T`. It has no relationship to the XYZ you defined a couple lines earlier. Since `T` can be anything (say, a `number`), there's no guarantee it would have an `isDirectory` function on it.

What you probably meant to do was to restrict `T` so it can only be an `XYZ`, or something extending from it:

```
type XYZ = Foo | Bar;

function bas<T extends XYZ>(x: T) {
  return x.isDirectory();
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrqegSwgEWwCcBTYAF3kIE8AKASgC5oAjREYsAOxQyz5LIBXQtzKFBxANy9MAX1TzUoSDABCYQjxk58RUhWr0mreOy48%20-YkJHQxE6X3mKyVAA7FoADQCaALWgAXjhEaAAfaHVCaVQAM0FOcmx4bmZIAB4AFWhiAA8yYk4AExhfPwA%20GlymTLoLLAFhblyAOlwCEnJKWjppWSA)

Comment: Oh stupid me, that makes so much sense!! Faceplam! Thanks for the explanation! Accepted once I can